# Get the frequency of elements in an array and store them in key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of elements and I want to get the frequency of the elements in an array, which is fine. How do I convert the object to store these elements and frequencies in a format to have property names or keys

```
     var array = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','d','d','d','d',] 
     obj = [{ element: 'a', frequency: 3}, 
            { element: 'b', frequency: 2},
            { element: 'c', frequency: 1},
            { element: 'd', frequency: 4}]
```

Right now I have a solution that just returns:

```
       obj = { a : 3, b : 2, c : 1, d : 4 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it using `Object.entries` like below.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 3,
  b: 2,
  c: 1,
  d: 4
};

const target = Object.entries(obj).map(v => ({
  element: v[0],
  frequency: v[1]
}));
console.log(target);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with destructuring.

```js
const obj = { a : 3, b : 2, c : 1, d : 4 };
const res = Object.entries(obj).map(([element,frequency])=>({element,frequency}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a map for quick & easy access while you compute the frequencies is a good idea but what stops you from creating the desired objects directly?

e.g. instead of

```
{ a: 3
, b: 2
}
```

Why not?

```
{ a: {element: 'a', frequency: 3}
, b: {element: 'b', frequency: 2}
}
```

You then simply need to `Object.values(obj)` to get what you want.

---

```js
const freq =
  xs =>
    Object.values
      ( xs.reduce
          ( (acc, x) =>
              ( acc[x] = acc[x] || {element: x, frequency: 0}
              , acc[x].frequency += 1
              , acc
              )
          , {}
          )
      );
      
      
console.log(freq(['a','a','a','b','b','c','d','d','d','d']));
```